# Nav bar will not highlighting current page using php

Tags: php, css

I'm using a template and trying to change the colors of the page, and I'm also converting the HTML pages to PHP. Once I did that, something happened and now I can't get the nav bar to highlight the current page.

[image: HTML of nav bar]

[image: CSS for active nav links]

I've been scouring everything, comparing the original with my modified page, and everything seems to match up besides using index.php instead of index.html, etc...

It's not working and I'm not sure how to get things rolling here. Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please post your code as text and not image.

Comment: When asking these questions, I recommend you provide a minimal reproducible example with the StackOverflow's `HTML/CSS/JS snippet` functionality.

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your files through a web server like Apache or Nginx or calling them directly from the browser or by clicking on the page files?

Another thing you might want to check, if you're using a template that might have JavaScript built in, is if it might be configured to strip out or work with a particular file extension.  For instance, it might strip out .html extensions automatically when implementing the logic for the active file, or it might keep them. So that's another thing to consider.

It's pretty hard to understand what the problem could be, just from this image alone.

Comment: Im running it on personal web server running linux. None of the javascript files have anything written for active nav bar links. Im not sure if I should put each link into another new class, or div....not sure if it will maintain the original formatting.

Comment: How does the template know what page to highlight as the active page?